# Make file two macros

Tags: makefile

I want to use macros in a single Makefile to compile two programs. When I run make, it produces this output:

```
Makefile:27: warning: overriding commands for target `compose'
Makefile:24: warning: ignoring old commands for target `compose'
g++ -g `Magick++-config --cppflags` -c alphamask.cpp
g++ -g `Magick++-config --ldflags` -o alphamask alphamask.o -L /usr/lib64/ -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lMagick++ -lm
```

It only compiles the second program. Is there any way to have the macros compile both programs? Here's my current Makefile:

```
CC      = g++
C       = cpp

CFLAGS      = -g `Magick++-config --cppflags`
LFLAGS      = -g `Magick++-config --ldflags`

ifeq ("$(shell uname)", "Darwin")
  LDFLAGS     = -framework Foundation -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -lMagick++ -lm
else
  ifeq ("$(shell uname)", "Linux")
    LDFLAGS     = -L /usr/lib64/ -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lMagick++ -lm
  endif
endif

ALPHA       = alphamask
COMP = compose 

${ALPHA}:   ${ALPHA}.o
    ${CC} ${LFLAGS} -o ${ALPHA} ${ALPHA}.o ${LDFLAGS}

${ALPHA}.o: ${ALPHA}.${C}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c ${ALPHA}.${C}

${COMP}:    ${COMP}.o
    ${CC} ${LFLAGS} -o ${COMP} ${COMP}.o ${LDFLAGS}

${COMP}.o:  ${COMP}.${C}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c ${COMP}.${C}


run:
    ./alphamask dhouse.png
    ./compose alphamask.png


clean:
    rm -f core.* *.o *~ ${ALPHA} ${COMP}
```

Comment: You could write `else ifeq ...` on one line and lose one `endif`.

Answer (score 2):

First problem:

```
COMP = compose 

${COMP}.o: ...
```

Adding a suffix to a variable isn't quite that simple in Make. And in this case you have some whitespace problems, which is why you're getting the warning messages, and why you couldn't build `compose` even if you tried.

Since you're a beginner, let's take a simple approach, crude but effective. We'll rewrite those rules, and add one at the top so that you can build both files with `make`:

```
all: alphamask compose

alphamask: alphamask.o
    ${CC} ${LFLAGS} -o alphamask alphamask.o ${LDFLAGS}

alphamask.o: alphamask.cpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c alphamask.cpp

compose: compose.o
    ${CC} ${LFLAGS} -o compose compose.o ${LDFLAGS}

compose.o: compose.cpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c compose.cpp
```

After you've got this working perfectly, a lot of improvements are possible.

**EDIT:**

Now that it's working perfectly, we can improve it. First let's put in automatic variables, to reduce the redundancy: `$@` is the name of the target, `$^` is the prerequisites, and `$<` is the first prerequisite.

```
all: alphamask compose

alphamask: alphamask.o
    ${CC} ${LFLAGS} -o $@ $^ ${LDFLAGS}

alphamask.o: alphamask.cpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $<

compose: compose.o
    ${CC} ${LFLAGS} -o $@ $^ ${LDFLAGS}

compose.o: compose.cpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $<
```

Now we see redundancy in the commands, so we can combine the rules:

```
all: alphamask compose

alphamask: alphamask.o

compose: compose.o

alphamask compose:
    ${CC} ${LFLAGS} -o $@ $^ ${LDFLAGS}

alphamask.o: alphamask.cpp    

compose.o: compose.cpp

alphamask.o compose.o:
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $<
```

Now we can replace the object (`.o`) rules with a pattern rule:

```
all: alphamask compose

alphamask: alphamask.o

compose: compose.o

alphamask compose:
    ${CC} ${LFLAGS} -o $@ $^ ${LDFLAGS}

%.o: %.cpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $<
```

And a static pattern rule for the executables. (We could use a pattern rule for these too, but that would be a little too general.)

```
EXECUTABLES = alphamask compose

.PHONY: all
all: $(EXECUTABLES)

$(EXECUTABLES): % : %.o
    ${CC} ${LFLAGS} -o $@ $^ ${LDFLAGS}

%.o: %.cpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $<
```

When you make these improvements, **get each improvement working perfectly before you advance to the next.**

Comment: tyler@Tyler-Satellite-A665:~/Desktop/404/assignment4$ make
Makefile:18: *** missing separator.  Stop. I get this error

Comment: Also what types of improvements do you suggest?

Comment: @user1210093: Line 18 is `all: alphamask compose`, is that right?

Comment: ${CC} ${LFLAGS} -o alphamask alphamask.o ${LDFLAGS} this is line 18

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see any problem with `${COMP}.o` unless you're in the habit of leaving trailing blanks around your code, and even then I wouldn't expect much trouble.  The revised makefile is too light on macros for my liking; you can at least use `-o $@` to avoid repeating the output file name in the link lines; and I'd still prefer to see `${COMP}.o` or a macro `COMP.c = compose.c` and another `COMP.o = ${COMP.c:.c=.o}` and use those where appropriate.  Avoid repeating any plain name whenever you can.

Comment: @user1210093: the missing separator probably means you don't have a tab at the front of the command lines; `make` is notoriously fussy about that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It was the tabs and now it works fine thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need a rule to make them all (using dependencies for both projects):

```
    all: ${ALPHA} ${COMP}
```

And then of course:

```
make all
```

Comment: I would like to have the macros do the work without having to type something like make all. When I had just one macro I could just type make and it would make it. Any ideas?

Comment: The best idea is to understand the tool you're using. From GNU make's documentation (http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), "[b]y default, make starts with the first target". If your first target is ${ALPHA}, then this will be executed by default. Putting the "all" target at the top of your Makefile will give the results you want.

Comment: If you specify no targets, `make` rebuilds the first target in the file.  Conventionally, that target is `all` and it makes all the things that should be made by default.  It is a pseudo-target, and in GNU `make` is suitable for being listed as a phony target: `.PHONY: all` (since you really don't need a file called 'all' lying around after the build).